# Removes elements at even indices

Tags: java

The `removeElementsAtEvenIndices()` Method should remove objects at even indices within the `LinkedList`. For instance, if the `LinkedList` contains `{ Apple, Banana, Melon, Orange }`, then after calling this method, the `LinkedList` should contain `{ Banana, Orange }` since Applet at the index 0 and Melon at the index 2 need to be removed. Each element within the `LinkedList` can be labeled starting the index 0, and based on this assumption, elements should be removed. If the `LinkedList` does not contain any element, then the method should not change its content.

I currently have this code, but it will only remove the odd indicies.

```
 public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices()
 {
     ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext())
     {
        iterator.next();
        if(iterator.hasNext())
        {
           iterator.next();
           iterator.remove();
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Your logic right now is *"skip one element, then remove one, ..."*. You just have to turn this around and do *"remove one element, then skip one, ..."*.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping with your current approach you'd do this:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices()
{
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();      
        if (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next();
    }
}
```

However, I would make the intent clearer:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices()
{
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    for (int i=0; iterator.hasNext(); i++)
    {
        iterator.next();
        if ((i % 2) == 0) iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

or maybe this:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices()
{
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    for (boolean even=true; iterator.hasNext(); even=!even)
    {
        iterator.next();
        if (even) iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can correct the problem as well as make your code simpler to understand by using a counter as follows:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices() {
    int counter = 0;
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can solve it by promoting `iterator.remove()` one level up as follows:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices() {
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public void removeElementsAtEvenIndices() {
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.remove();

        if(iterator.hasNext())
            iterator.next();
     }
}
```